# What's a word for opening and closing a store

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to use a term that defines the action of opening /closing.

For example if you are a shop owner and you open and close your shop at certain hours you can say we are open for trade at x.xx hours and close at x.xx. A way to describe this two actions is open/close shop for trade. what can I replace open/close with?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by combining the standard terms (open/close) into a single word?

Comment: just curious to see if there is a better/ simpler way to describe it so that I don't have to refer to it as open/close every time I need to (I need to do a it a quite a few times for the project I am working on).

Comment: Try *fungle*, as in *I fungle the store at 8:00 and I fungle it again at 20:00*. Now, quickly, what are its opening and closing times?  I mean, if there were a single word for both opening and closing a store, what use would it be, why you'd end up with something like *I fungle the store closed at 8:00 and I fungle it open again at 20:00*.  Linguistic madness!

Comment: *Toggle* is a nice verb for a change in state, e.g., on/off. Unfortunately we don't toggle stores (although you could toggle a store's automatic security shutter).

Comment: I could imagine some valid uses, but I don't think the word exists. You could say, "The shop is busiest at opening and closing times. This opening/closing rush needs more employees on the floor."

Comment: Why would there be such a word? Suppose you say "We fungle the store at noon." Nobody will know if you open it or close it at that time.

Comment: *Transition* or *get the keys out*. If you have a night crew (doing cleaning or replenishment) you could *change/swap shifts*.

Comment: @djumanji If you want to find the times of opening and closing of Mrs Sugarsnap's Sweet Shop, just search online for "Mrs Sugarsnap's Sweet Shop opening (or opening times) and you will find both the opening and the closing times. Why?  Because it's simple ans short, and obvious to the seller wants to know when on a particular day the shop will be open.  There is no need to specify closing.

Comment: You could say "We operate between x and y".